# Courses eligible for Skilled recognised graduate visa subclass 476

Tags: visa, australia, skilled-migration

I am seeking to apply for Recognised graduate visa 476. I checked the eligibility criteria on the govt portal. I am an engineering postgraduate in Automotive engineering. I am in doubt whether this particular degree is qualified under the criteria. I know for definite that the university from where i got this is eligible under Washington accord.